# Problems 'beautifying'/commenting Code

Tags: c++, if-statement

**What's the Problem?**

Running an if statement with 3 else if statements and an else statement at the end doesn't work.

**What do you mean "It doesn't work"?**

```
int handleArgs(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x = 0;
    if (argc <= 1) {
        return x;
    }

    x = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {

        string argument = argv[i];                                  // Convert argument to string

        if (argument=="-v" || argument=="--version") {                 //*** If user asks for version info ***\\
            cout << "\nYou are running \n  Dev0.0.0" << endl;

        } else if (argument == "-a " || argument == "--admin") {    //*** If user tries to open console ***\\
            cout << "\nSorry, console feature currently unavailable" << endl;

        } else if (argument=="-h" || argument=="--help") {          //*** If user asks for help ***\\

            cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0] << " -[switch] argument(s)\n";
            cout << " -a,  --admin        Open console view. Requires password\n";
            cout << " -v,  --version      Print version and exit\n";
            cout << " -h,  --help         Print this message and exit\n" << endl;

        } else {
            cout << "   Is you dumb?\nIncorrect syntax/argument(s)\n    '" <<      argv[0] << " --help' for help." << endl;
        }
    }
}
        return x;
```

}
Specifically, the `if(condition)` never executes even if the condition is true.

The 1st `else if(condition)` never executes either.

The 2nd `else if` statement executes if true.

The `else` executes when else if is true AND

1. The if statement is true.
2. The 1st else if statement is true.
3. None of the statements are true.
4. Not if the 2nd else if statement is true.

**Summary**

Basically, it's like the `if` and the first `else if` don't exist.

EDIT: The title has been changed from 'If Else Statement not Working C++

Comment: Paste the source code here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Replace the link?

Comment: Yes, like MikeCAT did.  Links can lead to viruses and stuff, short code snippets are much better.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true of the code you posted. Can you boil down the problem to a minimal, verifiable executable program that others can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Your code [do work](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xJ7VBo0MYSqNPsvE). Please provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MikeCAT Posted actual source

Comment: Try to `cout` your `argument` before entering the `if` statement first.

Comment: Your `return x;` statement is within your for loop. So the loop will execute at most once. I've properly indented code as to make it obvious to you.

Comment: i had to edit out some stuff; made a mistake. did some weird indenting stuff when i was editing @Joce

Comment: @WilliamChan `cout << argument << endl;` prints the argument, and prints it out exactly. No spaces, No tabs, The dashes, Everything

Comment: "should beautify my code" - improving the readability of your code is important.  Instead of abandoning readability, turn on more compile flags.  When I compiled your code in my environment and make, the compiler complained about 'multi-line comments'.  Fixing that alone might have lead you to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comments are not terminated correctly. The following works:

```
int handleArgs(int argc, char **argv)
{
int x=0;
if (argc <= 1) {return x;}
x = 1;

for (int i=1; i < argc; i++)
{
  string argument(argv[i]);                                  // Convert argument to string

  if (argument==std::string("-v") || argument=="--version")
  { 
      cout << "\nYou are running \n  Dev0.0.0" << endl;
  }
  else if (argument == "-a " || argument == "--admin")
  {  
      cout << "\nSorry, console feature currently unavailable" << endl;
  }
  else if (argument=="-h" || argument=="--help")
  {        
      cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0] << " -[switch] argument(s)\n";
      cout << " -a,  --admin        Open console view. Requires password\n";
      cout << " -v,  --version      Print version and exit\n";
      cout << " -h,  --help         Print this message and exit\n" << endl;
  }
  else
  {
    cout << "   Is you dumb?\nIncorrect syntax/argument(s)\n    '" <<      argv[0] << " --help' for help." << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thx, guess i shouldn't 'beautify' my code. Just caused me problems

Answer (score 1):

If you write `\` at the end of line, it means that the next line will be concatenated by the preprocessor. Then, the comment including the "statement"s with`cout` will be removed.

Remove these junk `\`s and format your code neatly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int handleArgs(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int x=0;
    if (argc <= 1) {
        return x;
    }
    x = 1;

    for (int i=1; i < argc; i++) {
        string argument = argv[i];                                  // Convert argument to string

        if (argument=="-v" || argument=="--version") {              //*** If user asks for version info ***
            cout << "\nYou are running \n  Dev0.0.0" << endl;
        } else if (argument == "-a " || argument == "--admin") {    //*** If user tries to open console ***
            cout << "\nSorry, console feature currently unavailable" << endl;
        } else if (argument=="-h" || argument=="--help") {          //*** If user asks for help ***
            cout << "\nUsage: " << argv[0] << " -[switch] argument(s)\n";
            cout << " -a,  --admin        Open console view. Requires password\n";
            cout << " -v,  --version      Print version and exit\n";
            cout << " -h,  --help         Print this message and exit\n" << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "   Is you dumb?\nIncorrect syntax/argument(s)\n    '" <<      argv[0] << " --help' for help." << endl;
        }
    }
    return x;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    return handleArgs(argc, argv);
}
```

Note: shouldn't the `"-a "` be `"-a"` (remove the space)?

Comment: Thx, guess I shouldn't 'beautify' my code. Just causes problems